# UITableView Custom Cell modifies on click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a table using custom cells. On every click, the custom cell style changes, like the content is changing the position. I've set the constraints, I've tried using

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

but I'm getting the same results!
Here's what I'm talking about: https://i.imgur.com/bSlTHnO.gifv

My storyboard looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHHg2.png

Label constraints: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3XMO.jpg

This is my code for the FeedViewController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var date: String?
var timeStamp : String?
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var refHandle: UInt!

var id: String?

var postList = [Post]()

let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

@IBOutlet var postTableView: UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    fetchPosts()
    postTableView?.delegate = self
    postTableView?.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return postList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: NewsFeedCustomCell = postTableView?.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell", for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedCustomCell
    let posts: Post = postList[indexPath.row]        
    cell.nameLabel.text = posts.name
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = posts.info
    cell.titleLabel.text = posts.title

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number: \(indexPath)")
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func fetchPosts() {
    ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            self.postList.removeAll()
            for childSnap in snapshot.children.allObjects {
                let snap = childSnap as! DataSnapshot
                let value = snap.value as? NSDictionary
                let title = value?["title"] as? String
                let time = value?["time"] as? String
                let privacy = value?["privacy"] as? Int
                let postDate = value?["postDate"] as? String
                let description = value?["description"] as? String
                let likesNr = value?["likesNr"] as? Int
                let commentsNr = value?["commentsNr"] as? Int
                let activities = value?["activities"] as? String
                let location = value?["location"] as? String

                let post = Post(title: title, name: "", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Post"), info: description, likesNr: likesNr, privacy: privacy, location: location, commentsNr: commentsNr, activities: activities, date: postDate)

                self.postList.append(post)
                self.postTableView?.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For the gray highlighting, just set cell.selectionStyle = .none; on your cellForRowAt. And for the movement of the elements, we would like to see your cell's label constraints.

Comment: Added the link now!

Comment: You do have a race condition. It looks like the data is downloaded. That process might not finish by the time the screen is shown. I'm not saying that this is causing your problem, but your app will not work well in the long run if you do not address this issue.

Comment: And what is the solution for this another problem? Managing the functions with async?